# How simulate an event that needs to be caught by an Event.observe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a function controlling the content of an element. This function is called on each `blur` event, using an `Event.observe`.

I tried to use `$(id_element).blur();` but the event was not caught by the `Event.observe`.

Do you have some advice? How should I simulate the blur event so it is caught by the `Event.observe`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to catch the blur event when it's fired try this :

```
$("body").on("blur", "#"+id_element, function(){
    //Do something
});
```

If you want to simulate the blur event see the .trigger() method.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a dummy example using JSFiddle, it might be the case that you are triggering event before declaring the event.observer...

[Observer](http://jsfiddle.net/rgyxe9d9/)

HTML

```
<button id='myElement'>Trigger window load</button>
<i>Have a look at your console.</i>
```

JS

```
$('myElement').observe('click', function(){alert('aaa');});
$('myElement').click();
```

Hope this helps you.